# How to save Javascript object to Firebase if object has functions/methods attached?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to synchronize the data attributes of a javascript object to Firebase. However, when I attach methods to my object Firebase throws an error:
**Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains a function in property**

I'm looking for a nice clean way to sync my objects without having to strip out all the methods, or create a `data` attribute within the object.

#### My Javascript constructor

```
var MyClass = function() { 
  this.foo = "bar";  // an example attribute. No problem for Firebase
}

// add a method. Firebase will throw an error because of this method.
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function () {};
```

#### Create a new object

```
var myInstance = new MyClass();
```

#### Firebase throws an error

```
firebase.database().ref().set(myInstance);
```

Any ideas for a clean way to make something like this work?

Comment: Save them as JSON without the functions, and then use a `JSON.parse` with a reviver function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var json = JSON.parse(JSON.serialize(myInstance));
firebase.database().ref().set(json);
```

But in general, I'd recommend keeping your code separate from your data. Objects from your Firebase Database should not contain functions.